# How to write syntax in internal css to external css?

Tags: css, external, internal

My internal css is this one:

```
   <style type="text/css">
       .OneClass
       {  
          background: url(/Images/star.png) no-repeat !important;
       }
    </style>
```

OneClass is name of a class attribute in one div in td tag.

When I'm writing in external css file:

```
.OneClass
{  
     background: url(/Images/star.png) no-repeat !important;
}
```

it's not working. Why?

This is how I include the css file:

I did notice strange behavior though:
In my css I color some letters red. If I change it to green, it's not changed in the result page (it's still red). But, if I remove the link to the css file, the letters aren't red either! Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you included your external CSS into your HTML document?

Comment: Is your CSS file in the same folder as your HTML? You might be having path issues.

Comment: Show us how you included the external CSS file.

Comment: It's probably because CSS is on a different location, and background is on a relative folder. Check it, try to put CSS on the same folder as your HTML and including it.

Comment: @RyanCasas They are on the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed /Images/star.png to Images/star.png in the .css file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime example of an "it's not working" question, so is quite difficult to answer, but I'll give it a guess.

When you include the image using the inline stylsheet, you use a path which is relative *to your HTML file*. When you move your CSS to an external style, I'm guessing your stylesheet is in a different place. This breaks the relative path. You need to show us how you include your stylesheet to give a better answer.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache, or `Ctrl` + `F5`ing the page (forces download of all assets). Also, please show us your `<link rel="stylesheet">` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reason is that your html file and your css file are in different paths. Copy your css file to the same location as your html file and it'll work.

Comment: Does the image `star.png` reside in a folder named `Images` that lies one level up in the directory tree from your css file? For ex: if you have your css in `/x/y/css/mycss.css`, your image will need to be in `/x/y/Images/star.png`

Comment: Can you provide the paths to your css and image files? Relative to your document root?